# Create insert statement to insert varbinary blob

Tags: c#, sql-server, blob, sql-insert, varbinary

I want to export some data from my DB and create an Insert-statement to insert those data into another DB with C#.

I made the script for working for nearly everything (and -type) but when I try to use it in one of my tables wich has a field named `Contentos` which is of `type VARBINARY(max)` I can't get it to work.

Now I have to select that data, which I realised by using a method which  converts a `System.Binary[]` (wich I am getting when reading the column) to a hex-string.

But unfortunately I'm failing when it comes to inserting that data...

I'm trying something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [My.Cool.DBA].[dbo].[Documentos] ([Id], [SomeID], [Name], [Contentos], [LastChange], [LastChangeId]) VALUES ('693c9644-f2b5-4c74-a633-f4942fc1d8e5', 'bca2ac27-71e0-4641-a4b0-3c3e39916e71', 'Whats that', [--> here goes the content <--], '07.08.15 11:18:34:383', '693c9344-f8b5-4d74-a633-f4942fc1d8e5');
```

The content (for example):

> '504B03041400000008091043E288E9E0D9EC7C1CEB6CF6A7E9290D5A4B04179E2A1B8FE350341542EA67DCCD96DC5E682FD14E7A61E70000002A0300000000'

Result: Cannot implicitly convert type varchar to varbinary(max). Use the CONVERT-function

Okay, let's do it!
The content (for example):

> CONVERT(varbinary(max), '504B03041400000008091043E288E9E0D9EC7C1CEB6CF6A7E9290D5A4B04179E2A1B8FE350341542EA67DCCD96DC5E682FD14E7A61E70000002A0300000000')

Result:

> Error at converting to `uniqueidentifier`.

The schema is like this:

- Id : uniqueidentifier
- SomeID: uniqueidentifier
- Name: nvarchar(max)
- Contentos: varbinary(max)
- LastChange: datetime
- LastChangeId: uniqueidentifier

No matter what I do, this won't work.

So I please would like to know how to

1. properly read the information from the reader
   ( I'm currently using: ) `sb.Append(String.Format("'{0}'", ByteArrayToHexViaLookup32((Byte[])reader[j])));`
2. properly create an insert query wich will insert the data into the db :)

Many thanks in advance!!!

[EDIT]

Here's the thing that finally worked for me:

`string.Format("CONVERT(VARBINARY(max), 0x{0})", ByteArrayToHexConverter.ByteArrayToHexViaLookup32((byte[])value));`

The `ByteArrayToHexConverter` has nothing special, just converting a Bytearray to Hex (as the name says it :b)
Also I had to let the server convert it back from the hex string to the original `byte[]`

**Note**: I need this to be able to execute generated statements out of a text file. So if you don't have this requirements, I suggest you take a look at the answer from **Thomas Levesque**

> You should use a parameterized query:
>
> INSERT INTO [My.Cool.DBA].[dbo].[Documentos] ([Id], [SomeID], [Name],
>   [Contentos], [LastChange], [LastChangeId]) VALUES (@Id, @SomeId,
>   @Name, @Contentos, @LastChange, @LastChangeId);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a parameterized query:

```
INSERT INTO [My.Cool.DBA].[dbo].[Documentos] ([Id], [SomeID], [Name], [Contentos], [LastChange], [LastChangeId])
VALUES (@Id, @SomeId, @Name, @Contentos, @LastChange, @LastChangeId);
```

Add the parameters to the `SqlCommand` using the `Add` or `AddWithValue` method on `command.Parameters`.

Using a parameterized query has multiple advantages:

- security: this protects against SQL injection attacks
- performance: since the text of the query is always the same, SQL Server can cache the execution plan
- reliability: you don't need to worry about how the values (numbers, dates...) should be formatted, this is handled automatically. There is no risk of incorrect formatting due to a different culture, for instance.

---

The format for BLOB literals in SQL Server is `0x<hex-value>` (no quotes). So in your case it will be `0x504B03041400000008091043E288E9E0D9EC7C1CEB6CF6A7E9290D5A4B04179E2A1B8FE350341542EA67DCCD96DC5E682FD14E7A61E70000002A0300000000`.

Comment: Thanks, that's right of cource, but I'm sorry to tell you that this method won't fit my requirements..
My task is to create multiple insert statements and save them into a `.txt-file` which I then can copy and past into the MSSQL editor to run them.

Comment: @probird, in this case your question has nothing to do with C#, you should remove the tag

Comment: I thought it has to do with it because I'm writing the program in C# and have to cast etc the results and pack them into the statement but okay I'll remove it.
Thanks, that helped me (0x) :)